Problem with ConcatRelated and its implementation
There is a table with data:
Table name it [was on treatment]
Number_medical_history - short text
ID - counter
datefrom - date
dateto - date
hospital name - short text

Query 1 name - [was on treatment query]
Query 2 name - [was on treatment query united]
There is a first query:
SELECT [was on treatment].[Number_medical_history] AS "Number medical history", [was on treatment].datefrom AS datefrom, [was on treatment].dateto AS dateto, [was on treatment].[hospital name] AS "hospital name", "from " & [datefrom] & " " & "to" & " " & [dateto] & " " & "in" & " " & [hospital name] & ";" AS United
FROM [was on treatment]
WHERE ((([was on treatment query].[Number_medical_history])=[Forms]![Forms_1]![Number_medical_history]))

Then comes the second sql query:
SELECT [was on treatment query], ConcatRelated("[was on treatment query].United","[was on treatment query]","Id = " & [was on treatment query].[Number_medical_history],"") AS United INTO healing_from_to IN 'C:\AAC\BD\Onlytable.accdb'
FROM [was on treatment query]
WHERE ((([was on treatment query].[Number_medical_history])=[Forms]![Forms_1]![Number_medical_history]))
GROUP BY [was on treatment query].[Number_medical_history];


As a result, it should turn out that the rows are combined into one, but there is something wrong with my SQL query, can you help me?
Thank you.
I tried to combine the data into one row by first selecting the necessary data using the Number_Medical_History field.
It turned out that when combining the data, only Number_Medical_History was displayed, and the second field with the combined result was not.

Strongly advise not to use spaces in naming convention. Better would be WasOnTreatment. Why is there no patient identifier in this table? Or is Number_medical_history for that purpose? Is there a Patients table where Number_medical_history would be unique? You want to save this data into another database file? Why? And why non-normalized? I am surprised second query would even open much less show anything because SELECT referencing just table name is not valid. Also, fields referenced in SELECT must be in GROUP BY or wrapped in aggregate function.

And including unique identifier ID in ConcatRelated criteria will not result in combined records, assuming that is your goal. Could edit question to show sample data and desired result as formatted tables. Output should be possible with only one query.

Alias field names should NOT be within quotes. Use brackets since you have spaces AS [Number medical history]. Don't use an alias that is same as native field name.

SELECT INTO will create a new table or replace existing of same name. What is your goal?

It could probably go like this:
Select 
    Id,
    [Number_medical_history], 
    datefrom, 
    dateto, 
    [hospital name], 
    "from " & [datefrom] & " to " & [dateto] & " in " & [hospital name] AS United
From
    [was on treatment]
Where
    [Number_medical_history] = [Forms]![Forms_1]![Number_medical_history]

and:
SELECT 
    [Number_medical_history],
    DJoin("[United]", "[was on treatment query]", "[Number_medical_history] = '" & [Number_medical_history] & "'", ";") As UnitedValues    
INTO 
    healing_from_to IN 'C:\AAC\BD\Onlytable.accdb'
FROM 
    [was on treatment query]
WHERE 
    [Number_medical_history] = [Forms]![Forms_1]![Number_medical_history]

using my DJoin function found here with full documentation:
VBA.DJoin
and previously posted here.

If not concatenating records, why have semi-colon at end of concatenated fields?

Your answer does not concatenate records which appears to be poster's requirement.

@June7: Oh, right. Mixed up two questions ..

I don't think using ID field (a "counter" - autonumber?) for function criteria will produce concatenation of records.

@June7: You are right. It should probably be Number_medical_history. Thanks.

And it's a text field.

@June7: Oops, missed that too. Thanks!

@Gustav the function is not defined in Access 2016, it is not practical if the user uses a different version of Access.

@WildYT: DJoin is not a native function, it is by me. It can be found via the links provided and will work with any newer version of Access 2007+.

Using ID = Number_medical_history in ConcatRelated function criteria is not valid.
A single SQL statement should be able to accomplish.
SELECT [Number_medical_history], 
    First(ConcatRelated("'from ' & [datefrom] & ' to ' & [dateto] & ' in ' & [hospital name]", 
          "[was on treatment]", "Number_medical_history='" & [Number_medical_history] & "'","",";")) AS United
INTO healing_from_to IN 'C:\AAC\BD\Onlytable.accdb'
FROM [was on treatment]
WHERE [Number_medical_history]=[Forms]![Forms_1]![Number_medical_history]
GROUP BY Number_medical_history;

Or this version:
SELECT DISTINCT [Number_medical_history], 
    ConcatRelated("'from ' & [datefrom] & ' to ' & [dateto] & ' in ' & [hospital name]", 
          "[was on treatment]", "Number_medical_history='" & [Number_medical_history] & "'","",";") AS United
INTO healing_from_to IN 'C:\AAC\BD\Onlytable.accdb'
FROM [was on treatment]
WHERE [Number_medical_history]=[Forms]![Forms_1]![Number_medical_history];

Or if there is a Patients table where Number_medical_history is a unique identifier:
SELECT [Number_medical_history], 
    ConcatRelated("'from ' & [datefrom] & ' to ' & [dateto] & ' in ' & [hospital name]", 
          "[was on treatment]", "Number_medical_history='" & [Number_medical_history] & "'","",";") AS United
INTO healing_from_to IN 'C:\AAC\BD\Onlytable.accdb'
FROM Patients
WHERE [Number_medical_history]=[Forms]![Forms_1]![Number_medical_history];

